# Определить состояние всех дочерних элементов по интерфейсу

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Есть форма `WPF`. На ней в сетках и контейнерах расположены кастомные элементы управления под одним интерфейсом.

```
interface ICheckControl
{
    bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    string Caption { get; set; }
}
```

Все они расположены нелинейно и не просто "болтаются в корне". Заранее неизвестно сколько таких элементов может быть на форме. Необходимо создать функцию, которая по переданному верхнему родителю возвращала бы количество `ICheckControl` с `IsChecked == true`.

Например, текущая проблема: есть фильтры для таблицы реализованные через `ICheckControl` и они накиданы во вкладки по группам. Каждый раз при любом действии с `CheckBox'ами` внутри этих компонентов нужно реагировать и показывать в `Header` вкладки (`TabItem`) сколько сейчас включено фильтров.

Вижу я это примерно так:

```
public int CheckedControlsCount(UIElement uie)
{
    int count = 0;
    /*...*/
    if((uie.Children[i] is ICheckControl)&&(((ICheckControl)(uie.Children[i])).IsChecked)) count++;
    /*...*/
    return count;
}
```

Основной вопрос: как мне пройтись по всем элементам такого плана (`ICheckControl`) на листьях дерева, корнем которого является переданный `UIElement` не принимая во внимание остальные элементы.

Вот так примерно выглядит структура нуждающаяся в подобном обходе:

```
        <TabItem Header="s" Height="30">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                    <GroupBox Header="d">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <common:CheckCombo Caption="f" ListType="yesornot" SelectedIndex="0"/>
                            <common:CheckCombo Caption="g" ListType="yesornot" SelectedIndex="0"/>
                        </StackPanel>                            
                    </GroupBox>
                    <GroupBox Header="h">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <common:CheckCombo Caption="j" ListType="yesornot" SelectedIndex="0"/>
                            <common:CheckCombo Caption="k" ListType="yesornot" SelectedIndex="0"/>
                            <common:CheckCombo Caption="l" ListType="yesornot" SelectedIndex="0"/>
                            <common:CheckCombo Caption="p" ListType="yesornot" SelectedIndex="0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </GroupBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                    <GroupBox Header="t" Margin="0 0 0 18">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <common:CheckCombo Caption="q" ListType="yesornot" SelectedIndex="0"/>
                            <common:CheckCombo Caption="w" ListType="yesornot" SelectedIndex="0"/>
                            <common:CheckCombo Caption="e" ListType="yesornot" SelectedIndex="0"/>
                            <common:CheckCombo Caption="r" ListType="yesornot" SelectedIndex="0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </GroupBox>
                    <common:CheckCombo Caption="y" ListType="yesornot" SelectedIndex="0"/>
                    <common:CheckCombo Caption="u" ListType="yesornot" SelectedIndex="0"/>  
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="2">
                    <common:CheckCombo Caption="i" ListType="yesornot" SelectedIndex="0"/>
                    <common:CheckCombo Caption="o" ListType="yesornot" SelectedIndex="0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
```

То есть нужно передать этот `TabItem` и получить количество всех `IsChecked` `ICheckControl` в нем. Таких `TabItem` много и они все разные по наполнению и верстке.

Comment: У вас нет вьюмоделей для таких дел? Или Вы пытаетесь свою бизнес логику натянуть на уровень представления?

Comment: @tym32167 проблема в том что я не могу на кастомный контрол натянуть модель. "binding можно задать только в параметре dependencyproperty объекта dependencyobject". А определить кастомный контрол как dependencyobject я не имею понятия.